# ChartJS - zIndex value for points/tooltips?

Tags: chart.js

Working with a line chart on ChartJS. When you hover over a point on the chart and the tooltip appears, is there a way to edit the layering (essentially zIndex value) so the tooltip would appear behind the graph point?

Basically, I want this tooltip to go behind the circle instead of like
[this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQKKO.png)

Comment: Please show (post) the code you already have, this makes it easier to propose an adequate solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

There is no plugin hook that notifies between a line and point draw, so best you can do is use the `beforeDatasetsDraw` hook to draw it in. By default the tooltip only uses the `afterDraw` hook to draw the tooltip so you will need to manually add the `beforeDatasetsDraw` hook to the Tooltip and set it to what used to be the `afterDraw` hook and make that an empty function like so:

```js
Chart.Tooltip.beforeDatasetsDraw = Chart.Tooltip.afterDraw;
Chart.Tooltip.afterDraw = () => {}

const options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
        borderColor: 'pink'
      },
      {
        label: '# of Points',
        data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
        borderColor: 'orange'
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
  }
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.6.2/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```